# what's wrong with my code here

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can somebody help me with this. Here I have a set of 3 different numbers as strings that I get from a user and I also have another 3 randomly generated numbers that I want to compare with the set of numbers that I get from a users but since I'm not gonna do any calculations with the number I didn't see any reason to convert them so I'm trying to compare them as strings

```js
function radGenerator(userno1,userno2,userno3,wnum1, wnum2, wnum3,dvresult) {
  $(wnum1).text("" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
  $(wnum2).text("" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
  $(wnum3).text("" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));

  var num1 = num2 = num3 = "";
  if($(userno1).text()== $(wnum1).text()||
     $(userno1).text()== $(wnum2).text()||
     $(userno1).text()== $(wnum3).text()){
    num1 = $(userno1).text();
  }
  if($(userno2).text()== $(wnum1).text()||
     $(userno2).text()== $(wnum2).text()||
     $(userno2).text()== $(wnum3).text()){
    num2 = $(userno2).text();
  }

  if($(userno3).text()== $(wnum1).text()||
     $(userno3).text()== $(wnum2).text()||
     $(userno3).text()== $(wnum3).text()){
    num3 = $(userno3).text();
  }

  $(dvresult).text("Winning Numbers: " + num1 +" "+ " "+ num2 + " "+ num3);

}
radGenerator("#uans1","#uans2","#uans3","#wno1", "#wno2", "#wno3","#divresult");
```

Comment: Please give a more descriptive title of what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare strings in JavaScript, you should the localeCompare() function. `"string".localeCompare("otherString");` will return 1 because "string" comes after "otherString". The function would return 0 if they are equal and -1 if the first string comes before the string you are comparing it to.